# iOS application Appstore submission issue which has having custom framework

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am facing iOS application submission issue.
In my application using bunch of nested custom frameworks which developed by me.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem. In short, I set the "**Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries**" setting to "No" in my targets. That worked for me.

You can try this

```
Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries: NO
```